# How to find differences between two ranges and then copy the row

Tags: excel, vba

I have two lists of order numbers on two different sheets. The first list contains an old list of order numbers that was not updated, and the second list contains old and new order numbers (as in the up-to-date list).

I'm trying to find the differences between both lists which should output all the new orders that were added, and then copy the entire row for each new order and copy this to the end of the first list.

I hope this makes sense. I have tried below just to test if I can pick out all the new order numbers and copy them to a third sheet to see if the output is correct, but no luck so far.

I prefer to do this in VBA given that I have order scripts to run with this data

Perhaps anyone here could help me. Thank you!

```
Sub OrderDifferences()
    
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Souce As Worksheet
    Dim Source2 As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    
    'outdated list'
    Set Source = Worksheets("Open Orders Intern")
    'up-to-date list'
    Set Source2 = Worksheets("New Report")
    'output sheet just to test if output is correct'
    Set Target = Worksheets("test")
    
    j = 1
    For Each c In Source.Range("D5:D250")
        If c <> Source2.Range("D2:D250") Then
            Source2.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Missing Rows

[image]

```vb
Sub OrderDifferences()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source (being read from) - up-to-date list
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("New Report")
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    With sws.UsedRange
        Dim slCell As Range:
        Set slCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        Set srg = sws.Range("A2", .Cells(slCell.Row, _
            .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge).Column))
    End With
    
   ' Destination (being copied to) - outdated list
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Open Orders Intern")
    
    Dim drg As Range, dfcell As Range
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        Dim dlCell As Range:
        Set dlCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        Set drg = dws.Range("A5", .Cells(dlCell.Row, _
            .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge).Column))
        Set dfcell = dws.Cells(dlCell.Row + 1, "A")
    End With
    
    Dim dMatches():
    dMatches = Application.Match(srg.Columns(4), drg.Columns(4), 0)
    
    Dim surg As Range, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(dMatches, 1)
        If IsError(dMatches(r, 1)) Then
            If surg Is Nothing Then
                Set surg = srg.Rows(r)
            Else
                Set surg = Union(surg, srg.Rows(r))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
            
    If surg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Old sheet was already up to date.", vbExclamation
    Else
        surg.Copy dfcell
        MsgBox "Old sheet updated.", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked! thank you. No idea it would be this complex